# Is there a difference between sabita (錆びた) and sabitsuita (錆びついた)?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

They both mean rusty/rusted, so is there any subtle difference between these synonyms or is one longer and that's it?

Comment: I guess 錆びた is used to describe something is rusty/rusted by observation(empirically).On the other hand, I guess 錆びついた is used to describe something is rusty/rusted metaphorically(My body is rusty due to lacking of physical exercise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you express the state of rust may vary from person to person, but I think that 錆びた and 錆びていた are obviously different.
Because it is difficult to explain with words, I searched for images by a keyword "錆" on the Internet.
Since I placed the representative images and arranged them according to my feeling, please have a look.

When something is very rusty, we sometimes say "錆｛さび｝さびだ！" to express it.

[image]